# Проектирование справочник - связи таблиц

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Проектирую справочник арендаторов (их сотрудников). Какой сотрудник, где находится и как с ним связаться.
Краткое описание: есть несколько офисных помещений (T1), о каждом хранится нужная информация. В каждом помещении по несколько этажей с кабинетами-офисами (T2). В кабинетах находятся разные фирмы (но это не важно), нужен справочник людей в помещениях (T3). Поле **ADDRESS_ID** используется в двух таблицах. Как этого избежать, чтобы потом не запутаться? Количество помещений, офисов может меняться.

T3 - **PERSON**         Люди

| ID | FIO | ORG | PHONE | **ADDRESS_ID** | **CABINET_ID** | ... |

T1 - **ADDRESS**        Адреса

| ID | CITY | STREET | BUILDING_NUMBER | DESCRIPTION | ... |

T2 - **CABINET**        Офисы с помещении

| ID | CABINET_DEC | CABINET_STR | DESCRIPTION | FLOOR | MAX_WORK_PLACES | **ADDRESS_ID**  | ... |

Comment: *Поле ADDRESS_ID используется в двух таблицах. Как этого избежать, чтобы потом не запутаться?* Это - ошибка. Адрес однозначно определяется кабинетом, поэтому поле ADDRESS_ID из таблицы PERSON следует удалить. *Количество помещений, офисов может меняться.* Добавить поле валидности в таблицы. Кабинет ушёл - помечаем невалидным. Восстановили - снимаем пометку. Ушёл без шансов на реинкарнацию - ну, можно и удалить запись, конечно, хотя что там тех записей будет? пусть лежит...

Comment: А если создать таблицу **LOCATION** (сопоставление **ADDRESS_ID** и **CABINET_ID**) и делать там, что хочется. А в таблице **PERSON** указывать не **ADDRESS_ID** и **CABINET_ID**, а просто **LOCATION_ID**? Так правильно будет?

Comment: Нет. Один ADDRESS_ID соответствует нескольким CABINET_ID, в то время как CABINET_ID соответствует только одному ADDRESS_ID.

Comment: Понимаю, что у персонала нужно просто указать CABINET_ID, а при выводе полной информации, взяв за основу CABINET_ID получать полный адрес.